# Github workflow + Docker + clang-format -> YAML invalid boolean for AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments

Tags: ubuntu, github, clang, github-actions

I have github Docker based workflow that runs on latest Ubuntu. During Docker image build clang-format 13 ( actually 12 is sufficient )is installed successfully. Installed from LLVM apt repository.

```
# Docker install commands
RUN wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
RUN sed -i -e '$adeb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-13 main' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i -e '$adeb-src http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-13 main' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt clean
RUN apt -y update
RUN apt -qq install -y clang-format-13
RUN ln -sf -T /usr/bin/clang-format-13 /usr/bin/clang-format
RUN which clang-format
RUN clang-format --version
```

````
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing intermediate container 832d6c401311
 ---> f07d8207d880
Step 17/26 : RUN ln -sf -T /usr/bin/clang-format-13 /usr/bin/clang-format
 ---> Running in e10be8661fa4
Removing intermediate container e10be8661fa4
 ---> 11807cadd21f
Step 18/26 : RUN which clang-format
 ---> Running in 6d5b832a6c41
/usr/bin/clang-format
Removing intermediate container 6d5b832a6c41
 ---> 3caf5986ca0d
Step 19/26 : RUN clang-format --version
 ---> Running in c2de46f5a1d2
Ubuntu clang-format version 13.0.1-++20211216073040+87ca22cba2fa-1~exp1~20211216193116.29```

But during the make build process it fails on code format check ( code format check passes successfully on host machine with clang-format 12, 13 )
```YAML:6:25: error: invalid boolean
AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error reading /home/runner/work/repo/repo/firmware/.clang-format: Invalid argument
YAML:6:25: error: invalid boolean
AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error reading /home/runner/work/repo/repo/firmware/.clang-format: Invalid argument
YAML:6:25: error: invalid boolean
AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error reading /home/runner/work/repo/repo/firmware/.clang-format: Invalid argument
YAML:6:25: error: invalid boolean
AlignConsecutiveMacros: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error reading /home/runner/work/repo/repo/firmware/.clang-format: Invalid argument
````

Please advise what could be the reason or how to overcome ?

Thank you